# Display timestamp in a text field and datepicker

Tags: flutter, dart

How to intl timestamp in 'text'  and option to pick datetime?

new to flutter

Text (''),

intl timestamp and option to choose one

Comment: Your question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

An working example:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:intl/intl.dart';



    void main() {
     runApp(Hello());
    }


    TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
    class Hello extends StatelessWidget {
     @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    String formattedDate = DateFormat('kk:mm:ss \n EEE d MMM').format(now);
    controller.value(formattedDate);
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: TextField(controller: _controller);
        )
    );
    }
    }
```

Comment: now and formatteddate -only static members can be access in initlizers

Comment: value-not defined

Comment: Just declare them as global variables instead of class variables. Global variables -> Outside any class or function (independent)

Comment: how would I do this part

Comment: //Declare as class or global variables
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
String formattedDate = DateFormat('kk:mm:ss \n EEE d MMM').format(now);
TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController(value : formattedDate)

Comment: I mean the entire dart file's code. Just edit your answer and insert the code.

Comment: String formattedDate = DateFormat('kk:mm:ss \n EEE d MMM').format(now);
    controller.value(formattedDate);